# Qlikview: Change color of all Expression headers in Straight Table

Tags: colors, qlikview

As the title says, I am looking for the option to change the colors of the headers in my straight table in Qlikview.
[image]

In the image: I want to change the color of the IPv4 and IPv6 Headers.

I tried setting the color by going to properties -> style -> background but that only sets the color of the field and not of the headers. 
I also tried right clicking the header and select 'custom cell format' but when i set the background color there, it doesn't seem to take any effect.

Comment: What version of Qlikview are you running? The `Custom Format Cell` option works for me as long as I don't have cell transparency set to 100% in the Style tab.

Comment: My cell background transparency is set to 0% and i am running qlikview 10 personal edition.